# Downloading file using IE from python

Tags: python, internet-explorer, com

I'm trying to download file with Python using IE:

```
from win32com.client import DispatchWithEvents

class EventHandler(object):
    def OnDownloadBegin(self):
        pass

ie = DispatchWithEvents("InternetExplorer.Application", EventHandler)

ie.Visible = 0

ie.Navigate('http://website/file.xml')
```

After this, I'm getting a window asking the user where to save the file. How can I save this file automatically from python?

I need to **use some browser**, not urllib or mechanize, because **before downloading file I need to interact with some ajax functionality**.

Comment: I believe that's a behavior defined by the user in the preferences.

Comment: I have looked at the APIs from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084%28VS.85%29.aspx# and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752085%28VS.85%29.aspx# and I don't think it's possible to save the file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This works for me as long as the IE dialogs are in the foreground and the downloaded file does not already exist in the "Save As" directory:

```
import time
import threading
import win32ui, win32gui, win32com, pythoncom, win32con
from win32com.client import Dispatch

class IeThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        pythoncom.CoInitialize()
        ie = Dispatch("InternetExplorer.Application")
        ie.Visible = 0
        ie.Navigate('http://website/file.xml')

def PushButton(handle, label):
    if win32gui.GetWindowText(handle) == label:
        win32gui.SendMessage(handle, win32con.BM_CLICK, None, None)
        return True

IeThread().start()
time.sleep(3)  # wait until IE is started
wnd = win32ui.GetForegroundWindow()
if wnd.GetWindowText() == "File Download - Security Warning":
    win32gui.EnumChildWindows(wnd.GetSafeHwnd(), PushButton, "&Save");
    time.sleep(1)
    wnd = win32ui.GetForegroundWindow()
if wnd.GetWindowText() == "Save As":
    win32gui.EnumChildWindows(wnd.GetSafeHwnd(), PushButton, "&Save");
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how to say this nicely, but this sounds like about the most foolhardy software idea in recent memory.  Python is much more capable of performing AJAX calls than IE is.

To access the data, yes, you *can* use `urllib` and `urllib2` . If there is JSON data in the response, there's the `json` library; likewise for XML and HTML, there's `BeautifulSoup`.

For one project, I had to write a Python program that would simulate a browser and sign into any of **20** different social networks (remember Friendster? Orkut? CyberWorld?  I do), and upload images and text into the user's account, even grasping CAPTCHAs and complex JavaScript interactions.  Pure Python makes it (comparatively) easy; as you've already seen, trying to use IE makes it impossible.

Comment: seems like you never experienced reverse engineering ajax requests for some 3rd part application full of weird dotnet 'ajax' widgets - pure hell.

Comment: @Paulo -- did you read my answer?  Yes, I've written 20 or 30 scrapers, entailing perhaps 100 AJAX or page requests that had to be reverse-engineered -- a big part of my job for more than a year.  They aren't easy, as I said, but compared to trying to do it through a freakin' COM object?  That's like trying to pick a lock compared to trying to pick a lock *wearing oven mitts* .

Comment: [HttpFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6647/) is good for reverse-engineering this kind of thing.

Comment: Thanks.  I use Firebug, where the Net option seems to be pretty equivalent to HttpFox, but to each his own.

Comment: Hi. If you at all can, yes, go with Pythons own network routines. But consider my case - we use a proxy which is authenticated with NTLM. For some reason, I can't get requests_ntlm to work with py2exe - at all. I must come up with something else, trying to find a workaround now. This rant was just to say, there are edge cases... :)

Answer (score 3):

[pamie](http://pamie.sourceforge.net/) perhaps

> P.A.M.I.E. - stands for Python
>   Automated Module For I.E.
>
> Pamie's main use is for testing web
>   sites by which you automate  the
>   Internet Explorer client using the
>   Pamie scripting language.  PAMIE is
>   not a record playback engine!
>
> Pamie allows you to automate I.E. by
>   manipulating I.E.'s Document  Object
>   Model via COM. This Free tool is for
>   use by Quality Assurance  Engineers
>   and Developers.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use IE. You could use something like

```
import urllib2
data = urllib2.urlopen("http://website/file.xml").read()
```

**Update:** I see you've updated your question. If you need to use a browser, then clearly this answer isn't appropriate for you.

**Further update:** When you click the button which is generated by JavaScript, if the URL retrieved is *not* computed by the JavaScript, and only the button is, then you can perhaps retrieve that URL via `urllib2`. On the other hand, you might also need to pass a session cookie from your authenticated session.

Comment: He/she said "I need to use some browser, not urllib or mechanize, because before downloading file I need to pass many ajax stuff."

Comment: That wasn't in the original question.

Comment: Before I will start downloading I need to login on website. Then click some links which will start some java scripts. Scripts are writing content of the website (without reload). This create new button on website which make possibility to download my file...

So I don't think that I can use urlib2...

Comment: Unfortunately "button" is:

<a [...] class="ptButton" onclick="exportSelected([...]); return false;">Export Selected</a>

Comment: @Adam: you can use urllib, but it means inspecting and reverse engineering the javascript and ajax calls. Besides being painful, it is fragile: if the site changes your app breaks. Consider asking the site owner to provide some alternative interface better suited for automation (like webservices), if it is not possible, good luck!

Comment: Thanks Paulo. I'm not working on that any more. The ajax stuff kiled me. ;) But who knows. Maybe I will back. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you can't control Internet Explorer using its COM interface, I suggest using the [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/) COM to control its GUI from Python.

Comment: Autolt look nice. But I want to write small application which just get this file and use data from it. I prefer some small smart solution...

Answer (score 1):

One option could also be to embed your own browser.

Thats e.g. possible with Qt via [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro) (GPL) or [PySide](http://www.pyside.org/) (LGPL). There you could embed the WebKit engine. You could then either display the page in a [QWebView](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qwebview.html#details) and let the user navigate to your download and filter that event or use a simple [QWebPage](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qwebpage.html#details) where everything could be automated and nothing has to be shown at all.

And [WebKit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webkit) should be mighty enough to do anything you want.

Very basic example:

```
import sys

from PySide import QtCore, QtGui, QtWebKit

url = 'http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/PySideDownloads/'

class TestKit(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.page = QtWebKit.QWebPage()
        self.page.loadFinished.connect(self.finished)
        self.page.mainFrame().load(QtCore.QUrl(url))
        self.app = app

    def finished(self, evt):
        # inspect DOM -> navigate to next page or download
        print self.page.currentFrame().documentElement().toInnerXml().encode(
                'utf-8')
        # when everything is done
        self.app.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    t = TestKit(app)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

I have something like that (an awful 3rd part application with lots of weird dotnet 'ajax' controls), and I use iMacros plugin for Firefox to do some automation. But I'm doing batch inserts, not downloads.

You can try record, edit and replay the inputs sent thru a VNC session. Look at something like http://code.google.com/p/python-vnc-viewer/ for inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely absolutely the last way I would normally do this but today I did have to resort to banging away to get something working. I have IE 10 so @cgohlke's answer won't work (no window text). All attempts to get a proper version of Client Authentication working were failing so had to fall back on this. Maybe it'll help someone else who's equally at the end of their tether.

```
import IEC
import pywinauto
import win32.com

# Creates a new IE Window
ie = IEC.IEController(window_num=0)

# Register application as an app for pywinauto
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
pwa_app = pywinauto.application.Application()
w_handle = pywinauto.findwindows.find_windows(title=u'<Title of the site - find it using SWAPY>', class_name='IEFrame')[0]
window = pwa_app.window_(handle=w_handle)
window.SetFocus()

# Click on the download link
ie.ClickLink(<download link>)

# Get the handle of the Open Save Cancel dialog
ctrl = window['2']

# You may need to adjust the coords here to make sure you hit the button you want
ctrl.ClickInput(button='left', coords=(495, 55), double=False, wheel_dist=0)
```

But man, is it horrible!