# Excel VBA controlling IE dialog box "Do you want to Open or Save"

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, url, download

I've been searching for how to press save when downloading file with IE and save the file under specific name in a specific location. 
[This is the screen as fas as I go with vba code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEW75.png)

My code looks like this so far:

```
Sub BrowseToSite()


Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLInput As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim HTMLButtons As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim HTMLButton As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "cboe.com/delayedquote/quote-table-download"

Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop

Set HTMLDoc = IE.document
Set HTMLInput = HTMLDoc.getElementById("ContentTop_C005_txtTicker")
HTMLInput.Value = "DJX"

Set HTMLButtons = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("button blue")

HTMLButtons(0).Click


End Sub
```

All other sources i have looked didn't worked for me, maybe I am missing something. SendKeys didn't worked either which I think is supposed to be simplest way of achieving pressing save button. What code should i use?

Comment: I think you have bigger problems than this. The warning on the bottom of the [CBOE Help Page](http://www.cboe.com/delayedquote/help) explicitly states that this auto-download is prohibited and you'll be blocked.

Comment: I saw that, nonetheless it still would be great to know how to manage that dialogue box to save, for any other occasion with the same problem, thank you

Comment: I suspect solving this general problem of using IE to download and save a file will involve using the `Win32 API` in a manner similar to [this Python solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4590561/4717755). You'll have to externally reference the `Win32` functions and grab the Save button from the security pop-up, as the Python example shows.